# Deploy cherrypy on apache with mod-wsgi

Tags: python, apache, python-2.7, mod-wsgi, cherrypy

I installed mod-wsgi and have a cherrypy helloworld code I want to deploy it to apache because I want to use multithreading and measure performance of cherrypy.
What apache configs I have to do including virtualhost and what to do with cherrypy code.

Answer (score 0):

try this...

```
<VirtualHost *>
    ServerName example.com

    WSGIDaemonProcess yourapplication user=user1 group=group1 threads=5
    WSGIScriptAlias / /var/www/yourapplication/yourapplication.wsgi
    <Directory /var/www/yourapplication>
        WSGIProcessGroup yourapplication
        WSGIApplicationGroup %{GLOBAL}
        Order deny,allow
        Allow from all
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/deploying/mod_wsgi/#configuring-apache

your yourapplication.wsgi file will refer to your webapp.py file.

Hope this helps!